# Cursor to fill @Table columns (with where clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that manipulates a data range according to a date column and returns data in this format:

```
myDates     myDataResult
2012-05-02  0.0208
2012-05-03  -0.017
2012-05-04  -0.026
2012-05-07  -0.009
2012-05-08  -0.013
2012-05-09  0.006
```

What I have in mind is to use a cursor to run the procedure several times on chosen sets of data(ID's), creating a table that combines the output to look like this:

```
myDates     ID1     ID2     ID2
2012-05-02  0.208   0.384   -0.123   
2012-05-03  -0.017  0.578   0.134
2012-05-04  -0.026  -0.045  -0.234
2012-05-07  -0.009  0.567   0.056
2012-05-08  -0.013  -0.481  0.034
2012-05-09  0.006   -0.113  0.187
```

I am stuck here:

```
Declare @TempTable Table(myDates Date,myDataresults Float)
Declare @IDc Int

DECLARE IDCursor CURSOR For

SELECT ID
FROM Top40_Key$ 
Where ID<5
Order by ID;

Open IDCursor
Fetch Next From IDCursor 
Into @IDc

While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin

Insert @TempTable(myDates,myDataresults)
Execute pro_myReturnTimeSeries @begDate='2012/05/01',@endDate='2012/05/18',@ID1=@IDc
Fetch Next From IDCursor INTO @IDc
End

Close IDCursor
Deallocate IDCursor

Select * From @TempTable
```

Is a cursor neccessary?  --I know it is not ideal in SQL.  (I am using SQL Server 2012.)

EDIT:  This is how the stored procedure looks if someone can figure out how to do this without a cursor:

```
[pro_myReturnTimeSeries] @begDate Date,@endDate Date, @ID1 Int

AS

Declare @prevDate Date

Set @prevdate = (Select Max(mydates) From Top40_Prices Where myDates<@begDate and       PrimID=@ID1)

Select * From
(Select T2.myDates,T2.Price/T1.Price-1 As myDataResult
From
(Select myDates,Price,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by myDates) as RowT2
From Top40_Prices
Where myDates Between @prevDate and @endDate
and PrimID=@ID1) T2

Left Join
(Select myDates,Price, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by myDates) as RowT1
From Top40_Prices
Where myDates Between @prevDate and @endDate
and PrimID=@ID1) T1

On
RowT2-1=RowT1) as Subquery

Where myDataResult is not null
```

Comment: How do you produce your original result? add that query to your question. P.S. `cursor` is very evil word, i would use it very carefully.

Comment: Can you modify the procedure to return the ID number as well in the result?

Comment: @Sparky , yes.  However the procedure runs with ID given as input parameter so you have ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you can do this without a cursor if you can rewrite `pro_myReturnTimeSeries`.   However, if you just need a quick-and-dirty answer: (changes to your code are inside the comment blocks)

```
--####
Declare @TempTable Table(myDates Date,myDataresults Float, [ID] int)
--####
Declare @IDc Int

DECLARE IDCursor CURSOR For

SELECT ID
FROM Top40_Key$ 
Where ID<5
Order by ID;

Open IDCursor
Fetch Next From IDCursor 
Into @IDc

While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin

Insert @TempTable(myDates,myDataresults)
Execute pro_myReturnTimeSeries @begDate='2012/05/01',@endDate='2012/05/18',@ID1=@IDc
--####
UPDATE @TempTable SET [ID] = @IDc WHERE [ID] IS NULL
--####
Fetch Next From IDCursor INTO @IDc
End

Close IDCursor
Deallocate IDCursor

--####  This defines which ids the labels "ID1",etc represent.
DECLARE @ResultID TABLE ([ID_code] sysname, [ID] int)
INSERT @ResultID VALUES
  ('ID1',1),
  ('ID2',4),
  ('ID3',5)

SELECT 
  [myDates], [ID1], [ID2], [ID3]
FROM @TempTable t1
INNER JOIN @ResultID t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
PIVOT(MAX(myDataresults) FOR [ID_code] IN ([ID1],[ID2],[ID3]) ) t3
--####
```

Comment: Thank you @Anon, this works.  However not necessary to create ResultID table.  ?  I can get the output with doing the pivot directly on TempTable

Answer (score 1):

If you can have the procedure return the ID as well, then you can create your temporary table to look like

```
Declare @TempTable Table(myDates Date,myDataresults Float,myId Int)
```

Then run all ID's and create one large @tempTable.   You can use the SQL Pivot command to spread the values across the 3 ID columns